# How to create and publish multiple Vuejs components on NPM using storybook and lerna?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-component, storybook, lerna

In the past week, I investigated a couple of articles about vuejs CDD (component-driven development) practices, and I found we can use lerna+storybook together for managing, developing, and finally building a style guide for the goal or publish components.

There are a couple of good examples at Github,e.g https://github.com/jsilva-pt/medium-reusable-vue-components , first problem here is they are some kind of Outdated and the problem, here is I want to use typescript with composition API and publish the built version not the sfc, scss,ts files to npm, How can we do this?

Answer (score 0):

here is my answer for React, but I don't think there is a big difference

https://stackoverflow.com/a/71462148/7180727