# How to setup storybook at root level lerna monorepo

Tags: storybook, lerna, stenciljs

I am working on a project which is set up with lerna mono repo, we have multiple stencilJS projects for an individual component inside packages of monorepo.

My project sructure is:

[image]

I am new to the storybook, now I have to set up the storybook at the root level which all the packages storybook.

I followed an article on the internet and I have set up something which works only for a single package component, due to the current style of setup.

Due to `defineCUstomElements` in `preview.js` it is loading the first project package loader I am able to see only the first project stories. Css is not loading for second project stories.

Can someone help me to set up a storybook at the root level which works for all packages?

My example

storybook/main.js

```
module.exports = {
  "stories": [
    "../stories/**/*.stories.mdx",
    "../packages/plugin-*/src/components/plugin-*/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)"
  ],
  "addons": [
    '@storybook/addon-links',
    '@storybook/addon-essentials',
    '@storybook/addon-viewport',
    '@storybook/addon-notes',
    '@storybook/addon-docs'
  ]
}
```

storybook/preview.js

```
import { defineCustomElements } from '../packages/stencilProj1/loader';;
defineCustomElements();

export const parameters = {
  actions: { argTypesRegex: '^on[A-Z].*' },
};
```

package/stencilProj1/component1.stories.ts

```
import readme from './readme.md'
import React from 'react';
import ComponentButton from '../../../dist/collection/components/ComponentButton /ComponentButton';
export default {
  title: 'Button',
  component: ComponentButton,
  argTypes: {
    label: { control: 'text' },
    type: { type: 'select', options: ['primary'] },
    disabled: { control: 'boolean' }
  },
  parameters: {
    markdown: readme
  },
};

const Template = ({ label, type, disabled = false }) => {
  return <component-button type={type} disabled={disabled}>{label}</component-button>;
};

export const Primary = Template.bind({});
Primary.args = {
  type: 'primary',
  label: 'Primary Button',
};
```

Answer (score 3):

After a couple of months of attempts, I finally solved this puzzle :) And want to share my solution with community

I have a lerna v4 monorepo for react v17 + mui v5 components written in typescript and flavored with storybook v6 and webpack v5

mui has its wrappers in preview.js, that's why I added the path to .storybook in babel-loader

```
module.exports = {
  core: {
    builder: "webpack5",
  },
  framework: "@storybook/react",
  stories: ["../components/**/*.stories.@(ts|tsx)"],
  addons: [
    "@storybook/addon-links",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials",
    {
      name: "@storybook/preset-create-react-app",
      options: {
        craOverrides: {
          fileLoaderExcludes: ["less"],
        },
      },
    },
  ],
  webpackFinal: config => {
    const {
      module: {
        rules: [, , , , , { oneOf }],
      },
    } = config;
    const babelLoader = oneOf.find(({ test }) => new RegExp(test).test(".ts"));
    babelLoader.include = [/components\/(.*)\/src/, /.storybook/];
    babelLoader.options.sourceType = "unambiguous";
    return config;
  },
};
```

it is also worth to mention my tsconfig has these lines

```
    "rootDirs": [
      "./src",
    ],
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample setup repo or something, as I'm looking for same?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to **import project 2's defineCustomElement with "as" to rename it** and use it?
(something along the line of following inside preview.js)

```
import { defineCustomElements } from '../packages/stencilProj1/loader';
import { defineCustomElements as defineSecondProject } from '../packages/stencilProj2/loader';

defineCustomElements();
defineSecondProject();
```

This is very manual and even if this works, if you have many repo might not be good solution but I've done something similar to load multiple component loaders and that seem to work OK for my use case in the past.

Comment: yeah this will work but this is not the ideal solution. I am looking for any other solution.